# Esri Map Android not loading on changing height of layout

Tags: android, kotlin, esri-maps

In my Application I two fragments in a single container. Half part of screen contains Esri Map and other half contains `ListView`. At this point of time Map and `ListView` are loaded fine, when I long press on `ListView`, the container height change and `ListView` show in full screen. But Now when I long press on Esri map I want to show it in full view mode by changing the height of Container. But Map is not showing when the container height is changed to full view(Match Parent).

This is my long press code in Esri

```
private fun onLongPress(){
    val params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
    params.topMargin = top
    params.marginStart = start

    val layoutTest = findViewById<FrameLayout>(viewId)
    layoutTest.layoutParams = params

    container.removeView(layoutTest)
    container.addView(layoutTest, params)
}
```

Below is My Screen shot to explain the flow 
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `visibility=gone` for the map with a large `weight` on the `ListView` then?

Comment: I tried it's not working

Comment: It should. And there are other ways of doing it. You should also post more code, we can't help that much with that few actual information.

Comment: @shkschneider Actually in my case I have an information of only about the longpress item that need to expand and that I can't set the visibility to gone

Comment: I believe you should show more code if you expect a precise answer. This is yet too broad.